# when using Hardhat doesnt exist create project

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity, hardhat

after maked directory and on terminal I typed 'npx hardhat'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOP4Q.png)

but doesnt showed create project
when i saw their tutorial, possible to create project
what can i do for make project of hardhat
I didnt do anythig else hardhat tutorial

Comment: i followed tutorial
1. mkdir hardhat_tutorial
2.cd hardhat_tutorial
3.npm init -y
4.npx hardhat

Comment: node version is 16.13.2

Comment: Can you list the content of that directory?

Comment: Did you find a solution. I am facing the same issue, I tried changing the node version to 16.11.0. But same issue

Answer (score 0):

I've never experienced any issues following the official hardhat documentation linked under https://hardhat.org/getting-started/

I suggest to start again and follow this doc step by step ;)

Answer (score 0):

you already have a config.js file, try this <npx hardhat --verbose>

you will get something like this  hardhat:core:config Loading Hardhat config from /Users/yashwanthreddy/hardhat.config.js +0ms

delete that and try